# О точке и не только — в смс

Tags: пунктуация, интонация

«Ставить точку или нет». Это название статьи, которую процитирую частично:

> Точка, несомненно, является одним из наиболее нейтральных знаков
>   препинания. По сути, она только отделяет одно предложение от другого.
>   В случае же, когда речь идет об СМС, точка стала своеобразным
>   маркером, определяющим стилистику и тон всего сообщения в целом.
>
> Вот почему нельзя ставить точки в смс сообщениях, которые вы
>   отправляете своим друзьям и знакомым. В своих сообщениях нужно
>   стремиться выглядеть искренним и эмоциональным, так, как это
>   происходит при живом общении.
>
> Вместо точек используйте либо переход на новую строку, либо смайлики,
>   которые передадут интонацию наиболее точно. Тем более, что сейчас
>   существуют сотни различных смайлов и эмодзи абсолютно на все случаи
>   жизни.
>
> В тех же редких случаях, когда речь идет об официозе, ставить точку
>   необходимо. Например, при отправке СМС начальнику или деловому
>   партнеру соблюдать правила пунктуации нужно обязательно. Вот вы и
>   узнали, почему нельзя ставить точки в смс сообщениях.

Статья за авторством Автора призывает избегать точек в смс, а также в СМС. Как вы относитесь к его аргументации и советам?

Comment: Автору нужно было начать с обоснования авторских вариантов написания слова "СМС-сообщение" :)

Answer (score 3):

Отрицательно отношусь и к аргументации автора, и к его советам, и к пробелам в логике. Также отрицательно отношусь к распространению этой информации в местах общественного пользования, независимо от мотивации такого распространения.

Answer (score 2):

Странный какой-то автор Вам (нам всем) попался!

*Вот почему нельзя ставить точки в смс сообщениях, которые вы отправляете своим друзьям и знакомым.*
Это кто ТАК за меня "порешал"? Если мое сообщение друзьям или знакомым будет бесточечным, они меня — такую — не поймут, потому что привыкли к определённому знанию языка. Возникнут вопросы (Ты ошиблась. Наверно, болеешь?).

*В своих сообщениях нужно стремиться выглядеть искренним и эмоциональным, так, как это происходит при живом общении.*
"Стремиться выглядеть искренним" и "быть искренним" — это абсолютно разные "вещи".
Я предпочитаю последнее: нахожу для небезразличных мне людей особенные словечки, обыгрываю только нам известные факты, ставлю восклицательные знаки, удваиваю-утраиваю буковки...

Грамотность — или есть, или ее нет, независимо от того, к кому ты обращаешься (у Автора — то СМС, то смс; определился бы уж).

Comment: Есть подозрение, что наш эмоциональный автор совсем не искренний, и не точка его цель.

Comment: Вполне возможно. Тем не менее, я "заценила" Ваш вопрос. Он заставил меня внутренне возмущаться: ДЕТИ, _вот вы и узнали, почему нельзя ставить точки в смс сообщениях._ Интонация нахальная, наставительно-поучительная. Главный специалист института русского языка нашелся!

Answer (score 1):

- Автор не учитывает возможные аспекты использования СМС-сообщений в
  будущем, требующие официального стиля или точности (пунктуация бывает юридически значимой):

  1. Удалённая сдача зачётов по русскому языку,
  2. Официальная переписка с прокурором,
  3. Ответы о своём местнонахождении инспектору по условно-досрочному освобождению и др.

Поэтому я бы предложил в интересах его идеи ввести автоматическую опцию "весёленько и со смайликами", отключённую по умолчанию.

Comment: Alex_ander, замечательное замечание!